# How can I truncate results after a certain amount of characters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel

I'm trying to truncate results after 32,759 characters, since that is the character limit in excel and that's where my results will be pasted.

Two method I've tried so far:

```
CONVERT(varchar(max), substring(comment,1,37259)) as [Comment]
CONVERT(varchar(max), ( substring(comment,1,8000) + substring(comment,8001,16000)...)) as [comment]
```

Edit:  It seems like the data isn't getting into the varchar(max) as it's returning results with only 8000 characters. This is part of a select statement.  I have no problem getting results over 32759 characters, it's just that they run into the next line when pasting into excel - which is why I'm trying to truncate.

Comment: What do you mean with *no luck*, what actually happens?, do you get an error?, the result is wrong?. What is the dataype of `comment`?

Comment: can you show us the table schema please

Comment: I can't replicate this problem [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26779/5), the issue does not appear to be with sql-server truncating the results.

Comment: I also can't replicate the problem. What is the data type of comment? Is it possible it is `text` or `ntext`?

Comment: Note that max characters in a cell in Excel is 2^15-1 = **32,767**

Comment: @barryhoudini I was under that impression as well, however I was only able to fit 37259 in a cell.  Certain characters may count as >1 character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this stuff shouldn't be necessary. If `comment` is `varchar(max)`, you should be able to say:

```
SUBSTRING(comment, 1, 37259)
```

If it is `text` or `ntext` then you need to convert it first:

```
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), comment), 1, 37259)
```

(Which is obviously much tidier than your solution.)

Comment: Much tidier indeed.  By the time I'm looking for an answer on SE it usually means I should've walked away from the problem 20 minutes ago.  Also, the length needs to be 32758 (I couldn't edit b/c it's <6 character change)

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, might as well toss this up in case someone else runs into this problem:

```
convert(varchar(max), ( cast(substring(comment,1,8000) as varchar(max)) +     
cast(substring(comment,8001,8000) as varchar(max)) + 
cast(substring(comment,16002,8000) as varchar(max)) + 
cast(substring(comment,24003,8000) as varchar(max)) + 
cast(substring(comment,32004,755) as varchar(max)) )) as 
[comment]
```

It looks like by not casting each piece the data size is being set to a data size/type that will accommodate all pieces.